# Python pandas dataframe: interpolation using dataframe data without updating it. Just get the interpolated value.

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I am fairly new to Python pandas library and cannot find answer to my problem in other posts. I have a dataframe that looks like this. Dates are index names and series are column names.

```
>>> MyDataframe
             Serie1  Serie2  Serie3  Serie4  Serie5 
2011-04-30      92      96     NaN     NaN     NaN  
2011-05-31     164     168      12     16      NaN
2011-06-30     238     242      90     20      88
2011-07-31     322     326     169     120     167
```

I would like to perform 1D linear interpolations within this dataframe but without modifying the dataframe, I just want to get the result. For instance I want to determine what is the value of Serie2 at the date of 2011-06-10. The functions `DataFrame.interpolate()` and `Series.interpolate()` seem to be useful only to replace the `NaN` with interpolated data.

Is there a function that could perform something like:

```
Result = MyDataFrame['Serie2'].interpolate('2011-06-10')
```

and it would simply return the linear interpolation between 168 and 242.

Thanks in advance for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interpolate` interpolates using the existing index, so you have to `reindex` the df and then call `interpolate`:

```
In [48]:
df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1])).interpolate().loc['2011-06-10']

Out[48]:
Serie1    188.666667
Serie2    192.666667
Serie3     38.000000
Serie4     17.333333
Serie5           NaN
Name: 2011-06-10 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Once this is done you can select a specific date and column:

```
In [49]:
df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1])).interpolate().loc['2011-06-10']['Serie2']

Out[49]:
192.66666666666666
```

Here I generate a new `datetimeindex` using the first and last values in your index using [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html#pandas.date_range).

It will be more efficient to just interpolate between the existing index values that are in your range.

We can find the lower bound of the index value using [`get_slice_bound`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.get_slice_bound.html?highlight=get_slice_bound#pandas.DatetimeIndex.get_slice_bound):

```
In [70]:
start = df.index.get_slice_bound('2011-06-10', side='right', kind=None)

df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index[start-1], df.index[start])).interpolate().loc['2011-06-10']['Serie2']
Out[70]:
192.66666666666666
```